# Is a trailing slash significant in a URL with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, url

I’ve built a React app using create-react-app. When I run `npm start`, the browser opens to `localhost:3000/proj/t`. (Note the lack of a trailing slash.)

The app breaks, because it can’t `fetch` a data file located at `localhost:3000/proj/t/data/file.json`. The app seems to be looking for the non-existent `localhost:3000/proj/t/proj/data/file.json`.

My `fetch` code looks like:

```js
const getData = () => {
    fetch(`./data/${slug}.json`
    , {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    ).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }
    ).then(function(myJson) {
     // lots of processing here
    })
};
```

If I add a slash at the end of the URL in the browser (`localhost:3000/proj/t/`), everything works fine. The data is retrieved from `localhost:3000/proj/t/data/file.json` and all is well.

In the above code, if I log `slug` just before the `fetch`, it always has the correct value: `file`. So that part doesn’t seem to be the problem.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make `npm start` open the url **with** the trailing slash? This would at least make development easier. (I tried changing the value of `homepage` in `package.json`, but the presence or absence of a trailing slash seems to make no difference in the (local) app behavior.)
2. Why is this happening? I thought that the trailing slash in a URL that ends with a directory was optional.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `./` from your fetch URL? I.e., `fetch(\`data/${slug}.json\`)`